# Where to place application/classes/request.php in Kohana 3.3

Tags: php, kohana, kohana-3, kohana-3.3

I am trying to extend request.php. Placing file in

```
application/classes/request.php
```

was working in older version of kohana. But id doesn't work in kohana 3.3. 
I have also tried

```
application/classes/Request.php
```

Edit:

File  is getting loaded. I think method instance is changed in new version. 
I want to apply following changes in kohana 3.3.
http://kerkness.ca/kowiki/doku.php?id=example_of_a_multi-language_website

Comment: Take a look at how it's done here: https://bitbucket.org/Battousai/kohana-multilanguage

Comment: Thanks. But I will try that one also. But after some work I was able to port above blog to new kohana 3.3.

Answer (score 1):

That tutorial is woefully outdated.  The Request class is now broken down into Request::initial() and Request::current().  You probably would want to overload Request::current(), but you will continue to run into issues following that guide with 3.3.x

Also, be sure to checkout the [API guide](http://kohanaframework.org/3.3/guide-api) for 3.3, it is on the Kohana website docs.